# NGRX - Catch action in multiple actions on single effect

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

I have an effect listen for multiple actions and do some code, each action may be dispatched in different orders, I need to catch when either the first and last action gets dispatched and do some logic before the map occurred, here is the sample code:

```
@Effect({dispatch: false})
    updated$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(
            actionsType.ACTION1,
            actionsType.ACTION2,
            actionsType.ACTION3,
            actionsType.ACTION4,
        ),
        withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(
            select((state) => state)
        )),
        map(([action, state]) => {
            let objectMapped: {};
            objectMapped = buildSomething(state, action.type);
            return objectMapped;
        }),
        tap( (result: any) => {
          // I need to know here when the first and the last action happened to do some extra logic.
        })
    );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "first and last"? How would there be a condition for "last"?Your task doesn't make sense to implement.

Comment: @xandermonkey sorry my question isn't clear, I'm trying to listen multiple redux actions in one single effect, I have a code logic that should be the same on every action and it works fine, not always all actions defined are triggered from different scenarios, I just need to know the last action triggered inside the effect filtered by the ofType. Is that make sense now?

Comment: Do you mean the action that was triggered last, or the last action that will go through the effect? The latter isn't possible...

Comment: Yes, last action that will go through the effect

Comment: How would you gather that information? That's simply not possible to do, unless you have the information at the moment that the action is created that it is the "last" one

Answer (score 1):

You can check which action is currently performed in effect with `type` property of `action`, to execute some specific code.

```
map(action => {
  if (action.type === actionsType.ACTION1) {
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't need to do something on a specific action, I just need to know when any of these actions occurred first and last.